# How to check if bootstrap carousel has stopped sliding?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I need to apply tooltip for the list that is feteched and shown using carousel.
In that list of items whichever  is wrapped with ellipses I need to show the tooltip for them.

But if I moveover mouse before sliding is completed then tooltip appears to be at the corner of page.

This is my code to show tooltip on mouseover.

I checked using .slid event given in their website &
also by checking if carousel-inner child is active or not but this also doesn't work and both these events fire before the sliding is complete.

```
$('.tooltipcheck').mouseover(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth)
        $(this).tooltip( {container: 'body'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's carousel has a callback that can be hooked into after a slide has finished sliding (called 'slid').
You could initiate your test in the `slid` callback, like so:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
    $('.tooltipcheck').mouseover(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth)
         $(this).tooltip( {container: 'body'});
    });
});
```

That way you're not calling the test until after the slide has finished transitioning, and it'll refresh on every new slide transition.

Comment: I have used that as well... but it still triggers an event before slide is complete. You can also check that by adding alert in slid event... I have mentioned that in the question as well.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be triggering before slide completes for me...  Could you make a jsbin of the problem?

Comment: ok ... i will try to do that.. just one thing... can i keep the container only div id/class ?.... because i want to show tooltip only for the elements which are in <div class="carousel-inner">.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: can i change **{container: 'body'}**?   & add div class instead of  'body' like {container: 'carousel-inner'} .. this carousel-inner is a div class

Comment: I don't know.  That depends entirely on what .tooltip does, which you haven't posted